# Set variable within condition

Tags: css, less

I need to set variable in LESS based on conditions.

```
@body-background-color: black;
@post-background-color: white;
@post-stacked-effect: true;

.content-padding() when ( @body-background-color = @post-background-color ) and not (@post-stacked-effect = true){
    @content-padding: 0px;
}
.content-padding() when not (@body-background-color = @post-background-color), (@post-stacked-effect = true) {
    @content-padding: 20px;
}
body {
    .content-padding();
    content: "@{post-stacked-effect}";
    padding: @content-padding;
    background-color: @body-background-color;
    .post {
        background-color: @post-background-color;
    }
    .some-math {
            margin: -@content-padding -@content-padding @content-padding;
    }
}
```

@content-padding is always 0px. Can you please help me fix that condition?

Comment: When I paste your code into [less2css](http://less2css.org/) I get 20px. The guards seem to be working as expected. Maybe you should elaborate on what conditions you're trying to set up.

Comment: I found that its working in JS version but not in php. I'm using PHP compiler and have this issues. It can be seen [here](http://goo.gl/6k952)

Comment: Looks like you found your issue. You are using a compiler that is not designed the same as the base LESS. From what I can tell, LESS allows a mixin to set a variable within a declaration block clear back to version 1.1. Yet it appears the PHP compiler does not allow that. You may, however, be able to leverage the PHP interface to do the check in PHP and set the variable in that before the LESS code is combined from the PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug in PHP Less Compiler. I have to do PHP workaround.

When I'm preparing variables for that compile i added function which calculates the padding in php and inject it into LESS.

Its only one row in PHP.

```
$lessvars["content-padding"] = 
   ( $lessvars["body-background-color"] == $lessvars["post-background-color"] &&
   !filter_var($lessvars["post-stacked-effect"], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) )
   ? "0px" : "20px";
```

Answer (score -1):

You are creating a new scope with the `'when'` guarded mixin which isn't visible outside.

So this isn't even supposed to work, and certainly isn't a bug.

You can instead create a function and call that from the 'when'.

```
@body-background-color: black;
@post-background-color: white;
@post-stacked-effect: true;

body {

    .padding(@padding)
    {
       padding: @padding;

       .some-math 
       {
          margin: @padding + 2em;
       }
    }


    & when ( @body-background-color = @post-background-color ) and not (@post-stacked-effect = true){
       .padding(0px); 
    }

    & when not (@body-background-color = @post-background-color), (@post-stacked-effect = true) {
       .padding(20px); 
    }
}
```

I've removed the irrelevant css, and renamed it because stackoverflow formats hyphenated function names weirdly.

Comment: Read the Less [documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature). As said in prev. answers and comments it's just lessphp that has improper scope of mixin variables implementation.